# Schema Error - Multiple Reviews should be accompanied by Aggregate Rating

Tags: html, schema

I have this schema set up, it is one rating for one product but I am getting an error asking for an aggregate rating.

As you can see from the image there are multiple products, but each one is enclosed with the code below.  Is my code wrong?

```
<div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
<div class="col-sm-8 no-justify"><p>
<span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"> Thats Insurance</span> Rating for 
<span itemprop="reviewAspect">Single Trip Gold Plus: </p></span></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 ">
<span itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating"><p>
<span itemprop="ratingValue" content="3"></span></span></div></p></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately at this time Schema does not allow for a review that has sub items that are of different types.

In this case we have a main rating
**Single Trip Policy Ratings**
and within this - Sub Ratings
**Gold and
Gold Plus Policies**

Schema presently counts each sub rating as a review of the the main rating. For things like Customer Reviews this would be correct, but in this circumstance it will not work as you will be asked to enter an Aggregate Rating - when there is no aggregate rating as these are separate items.

Having spent the entire day trying different combinations of Schema I am confident that this is the case for my circumstance.

Hopefully my answer will save someone wasted time searching.